# WhatsApp Cloud API suddenly getting Error #200

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

After weeks of having a WhatsApp Cloud API up and running, suddenly all my phone numbers can no longer send messages. Keep getting `(#200) You do not have the necessary permissions required to send messages on behalf of this WhatsApp Business Account`.

I have already checked the Meta Token Debugger, and my token has all necessary permissions (`whatsapp_business_management` and `whatsapp_business_messaging` (and `business_management` just in case)), and have added (and re-added) (system)users to my WhatsApp accounts w/ new tokens, but no luck.

I already have a support case with Meta, but so far they've been radio-silent, and it's kinda business critical to make sure my bots are able to reply to any request, so trying here too.

Comment: Already fixed? Came to this error today.

Comment: Yes and no. I ended up creating a completely new Meta Business Account and configured it (exactly as I did the other one) from scratch. That worked (for now).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's related to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/access-levels/ where for usage of "System user" auth token you need to request "Advanced Access" for your app within "App Review" -> "Permissions and Features"